# WPF Treeview: Specify TreeViewItem value member

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, treeview

I need to populate a Treeview with data from an XML. My XML schema is:

```
<root>
   <node>
      <leaf>
         <displaymember>String to Display</displaymember>
         <valuemember>Value</valuemember>
      </leaf>
   </node>
   <node>
      <leaf>
         <displaymember>String to Display</displaymember>
         <valuemember>Value</valuemember>
      </leaf>
   </node>
</root>
```

Obviously, there will be many nested nodes and many leafs within each node, but the leaf will always contain the displaymember and the valuemember element.

I am using the following code from another question ([How to create treeview from XML file using WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294882/how-to-create-treeview-from-xml-file-using-wpf)) to populate the treeview:

```
public YourWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BuildTree(treeView, XDocument.Load(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"testxml.xml")));
}

private void BuildTree(TreeView treeView, XDocument doc)
{
    TreeViewItem treeNode = new TreeViewItem 
    {  
        //Should be Root
        Header = doc.Root.Name.LocalName,
        IsExpanded = true
    };
    treeView.Items.Add(treeNode);
    BuildNodes(treeNode, doc.Root);
}

private void BuildNodes(TreeViewItem treeNode, XElement element)
{
    foreach (XNode child in element.Nodes())
    {
        switch (child.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                XElement childElement = child as XElement;
                TreeViewItem childTreeNode = new TreeViewItem
                {
                    //Get First attribute where it is equal to value
                    Header = childElement.Attributes().First(s => s.Name == "value").Value ,
                    //Automatically expand elements
                    IsExpanded = true
                };
                treeNode.Items.Add(childTreeNode);
                BuildNodes(childTreeNode, childElement);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                XText childText = child as XText;
                treeNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = childText.Value, });
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the second last line populates the TreeViewItem's display member (Header). I am unsure how to populate it's corresponding value member.

I'd appreciate advice on how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? A tree showing two lined header or just one line and a value to get when selecting the treeViewItem?

Comment: I want a tree where the leaf is just one line and a value to get when selecting the treeViewItem. The value will be a record ID.

Comment: You can add it as Tag, and get with when selected